# pacemaker: setting two fencing sbd devices to prevent spilt brain in the case that 1 sbd device is disconnected

Tags: pacemaker

I set up two suse 12 sp5 linux os vm and 1 window 2019 NAS vm.  Each vm has 2 network interface (10.10.10.x, 11.11.11.x).  I am trying to set up stonith( fencing) for eg two sbd devices (sbd 10.10.10.x and sdc 11.11.11.x) connect to nas vm  to prevent spilt brain so that if any network interface is disconnected, the linux vm will reboot itself.

I follow this url https://documentation.suse.com/es-es/sle-ha/12-SP5/html/SLE-HA-all/cha-ha-storage-protect.html#sec-ha-storage-protect-watchdog . if 1 of 2 sbd device cannot be accessed from the nas vm, the linux vm will not reboot itself.   The linux vm will only reboot itself when the two sbd devices(sdb and sdc) cannot be accessed from the NAS vm.  How do i configure the pacemaker such as way that if any of the sbd device(sdb or sdc) cannot be accessed, the linux vm will reboot by itself